How to Properly Batch Votes from zkSync Era (L2) to Ethereum Sepolia (L1) and Handle Gas/Fees? ZkRoolup
Body:
I am building a cross-layer voting system using zkSync Era (L2) and Ethereum Sepolia (L1). My goal is to allow users to vote on L2 and batch these votes to L1, where the main contract tallies them.
The workflow is as follows:

Users cast their votes on an L2 contract (VotingL2).
Votes are batched when the threshold (BATCH_VOTE_THRESHOLD) is reached.
The batch is sent to an L1 contract (VotingL1) via a cross-layer call.

Here are the simplified contract implementations:
L2 Contract (zkSync Era)
The L2 contract stores votes temporarily and submits them to L1 when the batch threshold is reached:
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol";

contract VotingL2 {
    address public l1ContractAddress; // L1 contract address
    uint256 public constant BATCH_VOTE_THRESHOLD = 1; // Threshold to trigger batch submission
    uint256 public currentBatchVoteCount = 0;

    uint256[] private currentBatchCandidateIds; // Temporary storage for candidate IDs
    uint256[] private currentBatchIndices; // Temporary storage for voter indices

    constructor(address _l1ContractAddress) {
        l1ContractAddress = _l1ContractAddress;
    }

    function vote(uint256 candidateId, uint256 voterIndex) external {
        currentBatchCandidateIds.push(candidateId);
        currentBatchIndices.push(voterIndex);
        currentBatchVoteCount++;

        // Submit the batch when the threshold is reached
        if (currentBatchVoteCount >= BATCH_VOTE_THRESHOLD) {
            _submitBatchToL1();
        }
    }

    function _submitBatchToL1() internal {
        // Submit batch to L1
        (bool success, ) = l1ContractAddress.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("receiveBatchVotes(uint256[],uint256[])", currentBatchCandidateIds, currentBatchIndices)
        );
        require(success, "Batch submission failed");

        // Reset the batch
        delete currentBatchCandidateIds;
        delete currentBatchIndices;
        currentBatchVoteCount = 0;
    }
}

L1 Contract (Ethereum Sepolia)
The L1 contract receives batched votes from L2 and tallies them:
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract VotingL1 {
    address public l2ContractAddress; // L2 contract address

    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public candidateVotes; // Track votes for candidates

    function receiveBatchVotes(uint256[] memory candidateIds, uint256[] memory indices) external {
        require(msg.sender == l2ContractAddress, "Unauthorized");

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < candidateIds.length; i++) {
            candidateVotes[candidateIds[i]]++;
        }
    }
}

These are sample codes to understand the exact logic.
VotingL2 contract address(ZkSync era sepolia) 0x9157167C34fc1C3A396daadcfCE93b1CfDE69Da2
VotingL1 contract address(Etherium sepolia) 0x7EBF808f2Ff1eEa59DE34968DACdBb48b037F3FD
The Problem

I deployed both contracts on their respective networks (zkSync Era testnet for L2, Sepolia for L1) using atlas.
After casting a vote on L2, the batch does not seem to reach the L1 contract even though the BATCH_VOTE_THRESHOLD is set to 1.
There’s no error message, but the L1 contract's state doesn’t update.

My Questions

Gas and Fees: Do I need to fund the L2 contract to handle the cross-layer call to L1? If so, how much should I fund it?
Cross-Layer Calls: Is the call method used in _submitBatchToL1 the correct way to send data from zkSync Era to Ethereum? Or should I use a specific zkSync bridge/relayer mechanism?
Debugging Tips: How can I debug the L2 → L1 submission process to ensure the batch is sent and processed correctly?
Best Practices: Are there better patterns or tools to handle batched communication between L2 and L1 contracts?

Any guidance or corrections to my approach would be greatly appreciated!
.
